# Is there a way to disable closing panes in Tmux?

Tags: macos, terminal, tmux, terminal.app

I am using tmuxinator. Here is my project file.

```
project_name: Network
project_root: ~/Code/Network
tabs:
  - editor: vim
  - worker: 
      layout: cd49,181x48,0,0[181x5,0,0{90x5,0,0,90x5,91,0},181x42,0,6]
      panes:
        - QUEUE=high,normal,low rake resque:work
        - 
        - 
  - console: rails c
```

Below is a worker tab

[image]

Is there a way to disable only for this tab closing panes? 
I would like to prevent this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to set the window option `remain-on-exit` to true for that window. I do not use *tmuxinator*, so I do not know whether/how this can be cleanly configured in that context. Here is how you would use a plain *tmux* command to set it for an existing window named `worker`:

```
tmux set-option -w -t :worker remain-on-exit on
```

This is a window option, so it will apply to all the panes in that window. After a pane’s command has exited, you can use `respawn-pane` to start its command anew.

```
tmux respawn-pane -t :worker.0
```

(Or <kbd>Prefix</kbd>`:respawn-pane` to respawn the current pane.)

This may not do what you expect, though, since *tmuxinator* seems to always create “default” panes/windows and then “type in” your configured command (i.e. the command restarted by `respawn-pane` will be a plain shell, not the command configured for the pane in your *tmuxinator* configuration). You may want to run your command in a loop instead (in your *tmuxinator* configuration):

```
while :; do QUEUE=high,normal,low rake resque:work; printf 'Hit enter to re-run... (C-c to abort)'; read; done
```